# Best typesetting of formula

Tags: math-mode, equations

Consider the following example.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand*\mathsetfont{\mathbf}
\newcommand*\DeclareMathSet[1]{%
  \expandafter\newcommand\csname set#1\endcsname{\mathsetfont{#1}}
}
\DeclareMathSet{N}
\DeclareMathSet{Q}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  &\{1983/4, 1985/4, 1986/4, 1987/4, 1989/4, 1990/4, 1991/4,\\
  &\hphantom{{}\{} 1993/4, 1994/4, 1995/4, 1997/4, 1998/4, 1999/4\}
   \subseteq \setQ\setminus\setN.
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

What is the best way to typeset this formula?

The reason I ask, is that I think my try looks 'odd' with `\subseteq \setQ\setminus\setN` begin just below `1991/4`.

Comment: I don't know what do you want, but if you really want scientific notation, may be working with modulus would work great. By the way @PeterGrill I think it's really common to use that, but with `amssymb` you get the `\smallseminus` which is better in my opinion (not the best, but better).

Comment: Just to add to aesthetics, why not use `\mathbb{Q}`, `\mathbb{N}` instead of `\textbf{Q}` and `\textbf{N}`?

Comment: @Manuel: Thansk. I did not know that. I guess I should look things up first before _ass_ uming I know things. :-)

Comment: @PeterGrill Just to add info that you are working with sets and not with numbers, functions, ... As I said `\smallsetminus` is more like a rotated minus and may be preferred for some people.

Comment: @Manuel: Ok, good to know that there are at least three symbols for set minus. But I still think it is clearer when you overload an arithmetic minus as it is an operation on two sets, not numbers.

Comment: Why `\subset` anyway? It's obvious that any finite set will be a proper subset. @PeterGrill `\setminus` is perfectly fine, that's a common way to express it. The operation is quite different from arithmetic subtraction (doesn't refer to the inverse of an additive group), so it definitely deserves its own symbol.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

My personal motto is *if I have a clear message to convey, it's better to make it obvious*

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,array}
\usepackage{xcolor,cancel}

\newcommand*\mathsetfont{\mathbf}
\newcommand*\DeclareMathSet[1]{%
  \expandafter\newcommand\csname set#1\endcsname{\mathsetfont{#1}}
}
\DeclareMathSet{N}
\DeclareMathSet{Q}

\begin{document}

\[
\left\{
\begin{array}{c@{,}c@{,}c@{,}c@{,}}
\ldots         &\ldots         &\frac{1983}{4} &\cancel{\textcolor{red}{\frac{1984}{4}}}\\[1ex]
\frac{1985}{4} &\frac{1986}{4} &\frac{1987}{4} &\cancel{\textcolor{red}{\frac{1988}{4}}}\\[1ex]
\frac{1989}{4} &\frac{1990}{4} &\frac{1991}{4} &\cancel{\textcolor{red}{\frac{1992}{4}}}\\[1ex]
\frac{1993}{4} &\frac{1994}{4} &\frac{1995}{4} &\cancel{\textcolor{red}{\frac{1996}{4}}}\\[1ex]
\frac{1997}{4} &\frac{1998}{4} &\frac{1999}{4} &\ldots
\end{array}
\right\}\subseteq \setQ\setminus\setN.
\]


\end{document}
```

[image]

You can actually make a new column type to ease up the entries. But I always confuse myself with `>{}`, `<{}` groups. Block selection of text seemed easier this time :)

---

EDIT: Converted to a sequence such that mathematically sensitive ones are less offended.

Comment: I do like this, but one suggestion and one comment. I'd put the cancelled out terms over 4 to be consistent.  Second, I am not 100% sure about a set notation with an element having a line through it to mean that it is not an element of the set.

Comment: Oh, and when you add the commas back in, do the commas as part of the "cancelled" terms need to be cancelled? :-)

Comment: @PeterGrill Indeed, but cancels ought to be read as discarded elements in the sequence not in terms of set notation.

Comment: @percusse: Ok, but its _not_ a sequence, its a set.

Comment: @PeterGrill Exactly. But compare the unnecessary complication while trying to be super precise to explain a very very basic idea instead of abusing set notation. I think formal notation can be quite redundant at times.

Comment: You need to put $1/4$ under each of the discarded elements. Or put a big $1/4$ out the front.

Comment: @SvendTveskæg I hope you mean columns :) If that is so it's my mistake replace the last `@{,}` with `@{,\phantom{,}}`

Answer (score 24):

Here are two other ways :

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand*\mathsetfont{\mathbf}
\newcommand*\DeclareMathSet[1]{%
  \expandafter\newcommand\csname set#1\endcsname{\mathsetfont{#1}}
}
\DeclareMathSet{N}
\DeclareMathSet{Q}

\begin{document}
The equation:
\[
\left\{ \frac{y}{4} \right\} \subseteq \setQ\setminus\setN
\]
where $y \in \{ 1983, 1985, 1986, 1987, 1989, 1990, 1991, 1993, 1994, 1995, 1997, 1998, 1999 \}$
\bigskip
\hrule
\bigskip
If we let $Y = \{ 1983, 1985, 1986, 1987, 1989, 1990, 1991, 1993, 1994, 1995, 1997, 1998, 1999 \}$, then
\[
\left\{ \frac{y}{4} \,\middle|\, y \in Y\right\} \subseteq \setQ\setminus\setN
\]
\bigskip
\hrule
\bigskip
The set $Y$ could also be expressed as
\[ Y = \{ n \in \setN \mid 1983 \le n \le 1999 \} \setminus \{ 1984,1988,1992,1996\} \]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hmmm! This might be the way to go. I'll probably accet this if nothing better comes up.

Answer (score 14):

Another take... *very* scientific look:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\mathsetfont}{\mathbf}
\newcommand{\DeclareMathSet}[1]{%
  \expandafter\newcommand\csname set#1\endcsname{\mathsetfont{#1}}
}
\DeclareMathSet{N}
\DeclareMathSet{Q}

\begin{document}

\[ \{n/4\mid n\in [1983, 1999]\setminus\{1984,1988,1992,1996\} \cap \setN\}\subseteq \setQ\setminus\setN \]

\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT:** ... or you may even completely do away with any explicit enumeration of numbers, if that's what you're after:

```
\[ \{n/4\mid n\in [1983, 1999] \cap \setN\ \land n \neq 4m \mid m \in \setN\}\subseteq \setQ\setminus\setN \]
```

[image]

Comment: Instead of `|` you can use `\mid`.

Comment: @Manuel: Thanks, that gives better spacing, indeed. I updated my code! `:)`

Comment: @SvendTveskæg: Thanks! Came up with another one in the meantime! `:D`

Answer (score 7):

Would this work:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{multline}
\mathbf{Q}\setminus\mathbf{N} \supseteq \{1983/4, 1985/4, 1986/4, 1987/4, 1989/4, 1990/4,\\
1991/4, 1993/4, 1994/4, 1995/4, 1997/4, 1998/4, 1999/4\}
\end{multline}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

What about:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath

\newcommand*\mathsetfont{\mathbf}
\newcommand*\DeclareMathSet[1]{%
  \expandafter\newcommand\csname set#1\endcsname{\mathsetfont{#1}}
}
\DeclareMathSet{N}
\DeclareMathSet{Q}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  &\{1983/4, 1985/4, 1986/4, 1987/4, 1989/4, 1990/4, 1991/4,\\
  &\hphantom{{}\{} 1993/4, 1994/4, 1995/4, 1997/4, 1998/4, 1999/4\}
   \subseteq \setQ\setminus\setN.
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
  \{y/4 \mid y \in \{1983,\dotsc, 1999\} \setminus \{1984,1988,1992,1996\}\}
    \subseteq \setQ\setminus\setN.
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

You may even consider using `\{\text{leap year}\}` instead of `\{1984,...,1996\}`.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up using the idea of [percusse](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/3235/percusse) in my solution.

**Code**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[
  locale = DE
]{siunitx}

% \nonly: non-leap year
\newcommand*\nonly[1]{\cancel{\textcolor{red}{\num{#1}}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
  \left\{
   \begin{array}{c @{\,,\,} c @{\,,\,} c @{\,,\,} c @{\,,\phantom{,}}}
    \dots          & \dots          & \frac{1983}{4} & \frac{1984}{4} \\[1ex]
    \frac{1985}{4} & \frac{1986}{4} & \frac{1987}{4} & \frac{1988}{4} \\[1ex]
    \frac{1989}{4} & \frac{1990}{4} & \frac{1991}{4} & \frac{1992}{4} \\[1ex]
    \frac{1993}{4} & \frac{1994}{4} & \frac{1995}{4} & \frac{1996}{4} \\[1ex]
    \frac{1997}{4} & \frac{1998}{4} & \frac{1999}{4} & \dots
   \end{array}
  \right\}
  =
  \left\{
   \begin{array}{c @{\ ,\ } c @{\ ,\ } c @{\ ,\ } c @{\ ,\phantom{,}}}
    \dots          & \dots         & \nonly{495.75} & 496   \\[1ex]
    \nonly{496.25} & \nonly{496.5} & \nonly{496.75} & 497   \\[1ex]
    \nonly{497.25} & \nonly{497.5} & \nonly{497.75} & 498   \\[1ex]
    \nonly{498.25} & \nonly{498.5} & \nonly{498.75} & 499   \\[1ex]
    \nonly{499.25} & \nonly{499.5} & \nonly{499.75} & \dots
   \end{array}
  \right\}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

**Output**

[image: output]

Comment: A typo on 2nd row, 1st col. That should be `\frac{1985}{4}`.

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[\left\{\frac{1983}{4}, \frac{1985}{4}, \frac{1986}{4}, \frac{1987}{4}, \frac{1989}{4}, \frac{1990}{4}, \frac{1991}{4}, \frac{1993}{4}, \frac{1994}{4}, \frac{1995}{4}, \frac{1997}{4}, \frac{1998}{4}, \frac{1999}{4}\right\}\subseteq Q\backslash N\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm not sure Svend is dealing with fractions... I think they are years

Comment: I should get extra points for the effort of playing with the big boys :P

Comment: Also: [Why not use the minimal class](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/42114)

Comment: @doncherry I'm using the `article` class in the real document and simply forgot to change it.

Comment: @SvendTveskæg I believe you misread doncherry's comment: the `minimal` class should _not_ be used for MWE's. The `article` class is just fine :)

Comment: If this is about years and not fractions, then what is the meaning of the formula? To me, it looks exactly, as if the formula shall state, that these fractions are rational but not natural numbers.

Comment: @SvendTveskæg Then you can use `\{leap years\}` as a set. Which will be quite easy to understand. Or the modulus notation `(mod 4)`.

Comment: @SvendTveskæg Yes, that’s what I meant. But I’ll take this as an opportunity to change that question’s title to something unambiguous.

Comment: @SvendTveskæg Then what's the meaning of "/4" and \subseteq Q\N?

Answer (score 1):

What about using `siunitx` package and adding the extra year as uncertainty?

Comment: What about it? :P

Comment: well, that could solve the problem of the visual `/`s...

Comment: I mean why not making a MWE for demonstration? :)

Comment: Hahahaha, ok, I'm sorry, I'll get to it

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered just writing something like `$\{k / 4\}_{k = 1983}^{1999}$`?